# Как имеющийся js-календарь вывести на разные страницы с разными данными?

Tags: javascript

Имеется календарь, который выводится на страницу Вордпресса для id="caleandar". Это календарь выезда туров, дата активна, при клике будет переход на страницу тура  конкретной даты. Мне нужно, чтобы этот календар можно было использовать много раз, для разных страниц, для разных div с id - id="caleandar", id="caleandar2" и т.д., чтоб на каждой странице календарь отображал свои активные даты.

Создал два тура, и внутрь вставил разные блоки с разными id - id="caleandar", id="caleandar2. Разные даты помещал в разные var events и var events2.
Создавал function caleandar и function caleandar2. Добился отображения разных дат   для нужного id,  но ВСЕГДА отображается только один календарь на какой-то одной странице тура, никакой комбинацией не добился отображения календаря на обеих страницах.

Возможно в element проблема. Знания и опыт закончились. Помогите, пожалуйста!
Спасибо всем, кто ответит!

```js
/*
          Author: Jack Ducasse;
          Version: 0.1.0;
          (◠‿◠✿)
        */
var Calendar = function(model, options, date) {
  // Default Values
  this.Options = {
    Color: '',
    LinkColor: '',
    NavShow: true,
    NavVertical: false,
    NavLocation: '',
    DateTimeShow: true,
    DateTimeFormat: 'mmm, yyyy',
    DatetimeLocation: '',
    EventClick: '',
    EventTargetWholeDay: false,
    DisabledDays: [],
    ModelChange: model
  };
  // Overwriting default values
  for (var key in options) {
    this.Options[key] = typeof options[key] == 'string' ? options[key].toLowerCase() : options[key];
  }

  model ? this.Model = model : this.Model = {};
  this.Today = new Date();

  this.Selected = this.Today
  this.Today.Month = this.Today.getMonth();
  this.Today.Year = this.Today.getFullYear();
  if (date) {
    this.Selected = date
  }
  this.Selected.Month = this.Selected.getMonth();
  this.Selected.Year = this.Selected.getFullYear();

  this.Selected.Days = new Date(this.Selected.Year, (this.Selected.Month + 1), 0).getDate();
  this.Selected.FirstDay = new Date(this.Selected.Year, (this.Selected.Month), 1).getDay();
  this.Selected.LastDay = new Date(this.Selected.Year, (this.Selected.Month + 1), 0).getDay();

  this.Prev = new Date(this.Selected.Year, (this.Selected.Month - 1), 1);
  if (this.Selected.Month == 0) {
    this.Prev = new Date(this.Selected.Year - 1, 11, 1);
  }
  this.Prev.Days = new Date(this.Prev.getFullYear(), (this.Prev.getMonth() + 1), 0).getDate();
};

function createCalendar(calendar, element, adjuster) {
  if (typeof adjuster !== 'undefined') {
    var newDate = new Date(calendar.Selected.Year, calendar.Selected.Month + adjuster, 1);
    calendar = new Calendar(calendar.Model, calendar.Options, newDate);
    element.innerHTML = '';
  } else {
    for (var key in calendar.Options) {
      typeof calendar.Options[key] != 'function' && typeof calendar.Options[key] != 'object' && calendar.Options[key] ? element.className += " " + key + "-" + calendar.Options[key] : 0;
    }
  }
  var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

  function AddSidebar() {
    var sidebar = document.createElement('div');
    sidebar.className += 'cld-sidebar';

    var monthList = document.createElement('ul');
    monthList.className += 'cld-monthList';

    for (var i = 0; i < months.length - 3; i++) {
      var x = document.createElement('li');
      x.className += 'cld-month';
      var n = i - (4 - calendar.Selected.Month);
      // Account for overflowing month values
      if (n < 0) {
        n += 12;
      } else if (n > 11) {
        n -= 12;
      }
      // Add Appropriate Class
      if (i == 0) {
        x.className += ' cld-rwd cld-nav';
        x.addEventListener('click', function() {
          typeof calendar.Options.ModelChange == 'function' ? calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange() : calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange;
          createCalendar(calendar, element, -1);
        });
        x.innerHTML += '<svg height="15" width="15" viewBox="0 0 100 75" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"><polyline points="0,75 100,75 50,0"></polyline></svg>';
      } else if (i == months.length - 4) {
        x.className += ' cld-fwd cld-nav';
        x.addEventListener('click', function() {
          typeof calendar.Options.ModelChange == 'function' ? calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange() : calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange;
          createCalendar(calendar, element, 1);
        });
        x.innerHTML += '<svg height="15" width="15" viewBox="0 0 100 75" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"><polyline points="0,0 100,0 50,75"></polyline></svg>';
      } else {
        if (i < 4) {
          x.className += ' cld-pre';
        } else if (i > 4) {
          x.className += ' cld-post';
        } else {
          x.className += ' cld-curr';
        }

        //prevent losing var adj value (for whatever reason that is happening)
        (function() {
          var adj = (i - 4);
          //x.addEventListener('click', function(){createCalendar(calendar, element, adj);console.log('kk', adj);} );
          x.addEventListener('click', function() {
            typeof calendar.Options.ModelChange == 'function' ? calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange() : calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange;
            createCalendar(calendar, element, adj);
          });
          x.setAttribute('style', 'opacity:' + (1 - Math.abs(adj) / 4));
          x.innerHTML += months[n].substr(0, 3);
        }()); // immediate invocation

        if (n == 0) {
          var y = document.createElement('li');
          y.className += 'cld-year';
          if (i < 5) {
            y.innerHTML += calendar.Selected.Year;
          } else {
            y.innerHTML += calendar.Selected.Year + 1;
          }
          monthList.appendChild(y);
        }
      }
      monthList.appendChild(x);
    }
    sidebar.appendChild(monthList);
    if (calendar.Options.NavLocation) {
      document.getElementById(calendar.Options.NavLocation).innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById(calendar.Options.NavLocation).appendChild(sidebar);
    } else {
      element.appendChild(sidebar);
    }
  }

  var mainSection = document.createElement('div');
  mainSection.className += "cld-main";

  function AddDateTime() {
    var datetime = document.createElement('div');
    datetime.className += "cld-datetime";
    if (calendar.Options.NavShow && !calendar.Options.NavVertical) {
      var rwd = document.createElement('div');
      rwd.className += " cld-rwd cld-nav";
      rwd.addEventListener('click', function() {
        createCalendar(calendar, element, -1);
      });
      rwd.innerHTML = '<svg height="15" width="15" viewBox="0 0 75 100" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"><polyline points="0,50 75,0 75,100"></polyline></svg>';
      datetime.appendChild(rwd);
    }
    var today = document.createElement('div');
    today.className += ' today';
    today.innerHTML = months[calendar.Selected.Month] + ", " + calendar.Selected.Year;
    datetime.appendChild(today);
    if (calendar.Options.NavShow && !calendar.Options.NavVertical) {
      var fwd = document.createElement('div');
      fwd.className += " cld-fwd cld-nav";
      fwd.addEventListener('click', function() {
        createCalendar(calendar, element, 1);
      });
      fwd.innerHTML = '<svg height="15" width="15" viewBox="0 0 75 100" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"><polyline points="0,0 75,50 0,100"></polyline></svg>';
      datetime.appendChild(fwd);
    }
    if (calendar.Options.DatetimeLocation) {
      document.getElementById(calendar.Options.DatetimeLocation).innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById(calendar.Options.DatetimeLocation).appendChild(datetime);
    } else {
      mainSection.appendChild(datetime);
    }
  }

  function AddLabels() {
    var labels = document.createElement('ul');
    labels.className = 'cld-labels';
    var labelsList = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
    for (var i = 0; i < labelsList.length; i++) {
      var label = document.createElement('li');
      label.className += "cld-label";
      label.innerHTML = labelsList[i];
      labels.appendChild(label);
    }
    mainSection.appendChild(labels);
  }

  function AddDays() {
    // Create Number Element
    function DayNumber(n) {
      var number = document.createElement('p');
      number.className += "cld-number";
      number.innerHTML += n;
      return number;
    }
    var days = document.createElement('ul');
    days.className += "cld-days";
    // Previous Month's Days
    for (var i = 0; i < (calendar.Selected.FirstDay); i++) {
      var day = document.createElement('li');
      day.className += "cld-day prevMonth";
      //Disabled Days
      var d = i % 7;
      for (var q = 0; q < calendar.Options.DisabledDays.length; q++) {
        if (d == calendar.Options.DisabledDays[q]) {
          day.className += " disableDay";
        }
      }

      var number = DayNumber((calendar.Prev.Days - calendar.Selected.FirstDay) + (i + 1));
      day.appendChild(number);

      days.appendChild(day);
    }
    // Current Month's Days
    for (var i = 0; i < calendar.Selected.Days; i++) {
      var day = document.createElement('li');
      day.className += "cld-day currMonth";
      //Disabled Days
      var d = (i + calendar.Selected.FirstDay) % 7;
      for (var q = 0; q < calendar.Options.DisabledDays.length; q++) {
        if (d == calendar.Options.DisabledDays[q]) {
          day.className += " disableDay";
        }
      }
      var number = DayNumber(i + 1);
      // Check Date against Event Dates
      for (var n = 0; n < calendar.Model.length; n++) {
        var evDate = calendar.Model[n].Date;
        var toDate = new Date(calendar.Selected.Year, calendar.Selected.Month, (i + 1));
        if (evDate.getTime() == toDate.getTime()) {
          number.className += " eventday";
          var title = document.createElement('span');
          title.className += "cld-title";
          if (typeof calendar.Model[n].Link == 'function' || calendar.Options.EventClick) {
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.setAttribute('href', '#');
            a.innerHTML += calendar.Model[n].Title;
            if (calendar.Options.EventClick) {
              var z = calendar.Model[n].Link;
              if (typeof calendar.Model[n].Link != 'string') {
                a.addEventListener('click', calendar.Options.EventClick.bind.apply(calendar.Options.EventClick, [null].concat(z)));
                if (calendar.Options.EventTargetWholeDay) {
                  day.className += " clickable";
                  day.addEventListener('click', calendar.Options.EventClick.bind.apply(calendar.Options.EventClick, [null].concat(z)));
                }
              } else {
                a.addEventListener('click', calendar.Options.EventClick.bind(null, z));
                if (calendar.Options.EventTargetWholeDay) {
                  day.className += " clickable";
                  day.addEventListener('click', calendar.Options.EventClick.bind(null, z));
                }
              }
            } else {
              a.addEventListener('click', calendar.Model[n].Link);
              if (calendar.Options.EventTargetWholeDay) {
                day.className += " clickable";
                day.addEventListener('click', calendar.Model[n].Link);
              }
            }
            title.appendChild(a);
          } else {
            title.innerHTML += '<a href="' + calendar.Model[n].Link + '">' + calendar.Model[n].Title + '</a>';
          }
          number.appendChild(title);
        }
      }
      day.appendChild(number);
      // If Today..
      if ((i + 1) == calendar.Today.getDate() && calendar.Selected.Month == calendar.Today.Month && calendar.Selected.Year == calendar.Today.Year) {
        day.className += " today";
      }
      days.appendChild(day);
    }
    // Next Month's Days
    // Always same amount of days in calander
    var extraDays = 13;
    if (days.children.length > 35) {
      extraDays = 6;
    } else if (days.children.length < 29) {
      extraDays = 20;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < (extraDays - calendar.Selected.LastDay); i++) {
      var day = document.createElement('li');
      day.className += "cld-day nextMonth";
      //Disabled Days
      var d = (i + calendar.Selected.LastDay + 1) % 7;
      for (var q = 0; q < calendar.Options.DisabledDays.length; q++) {
        if (d == calendar.Options.DisabledDays[q]) {
          day.className += " disableDay";
        }
      }

      var number = DayNumber(i + 1);
      day.appendChild(number);

      days.appendChild(day);
    }
    mainSection.appendChild(days);
  }
  if (calendar.Options.Color) {
    mainSection.innerHTML += '<style>.cld-main{color:' + calendar.Options.Color + ';}</style>';
  }
  if (calendar.Options.LinkColor) {
    mainSection.innerHTML += '<style>.cld-title a{color:' + calendar.Options.LinkColor + ';}</style>';
  }
  element.appendChild(mainSection);

  if (calendar.Options.NavShow && calendar.Options.NavVertical) {
    AddSidebar();
  }
  if (calendar.Options.DateTimeShow) {
    AddDateTime();
  }
  AddLabels();
  AddDays();
}

function caleandar(el, data, settings) {
  var obj = new Calendar(data, settings);
  createCalendar(obj, el);
} 
  var events = [{
      'Date': new Date(2020, 0, 07),
      'Title': 'Doctor appointment at 3:25pm.'
    },
    {
      'Date': new Date(2020, 0, 28),
      'Link': 'https://garfield.com'
    },
    {
      'Date': new Date(2020, 0, 27),
      'Link': 'http://google.com/'
    },
  ];

var settings = {
  Color: 'blue',
  LinkColor: 'red',
  EventClick: ''
};

var element = document.getElementById('caleandar');
caleandar(element, events, settings);
```

```css
.cld-main {
  width: 330px;
}

.cld-main a {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.cld-datetime {
  position: relative;
  width: 66%;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cld-datetime .today {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.cld-nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.cld-nav:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cld-nav:hover svg {
  fill: #666;
}

.cld-rwd {
  float: left;
}

.cld-fwd {
  float: right;
}

.cld-nav svg:hover {}

.cld-labels,
.cld-days {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.cld-label,
.cld-day {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14.28%;
  text-align: center;
}

.cld-day.today .cld-number {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
}

.cld-day.disableDay {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.cld-day.nextMonth,
.cld-day.prevMonth {
  opacity: 0.33;
}

.cld-number {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.cld-title {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  display: none;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.cld-number:hover .cld-title {
  display: block;
}

.cld-title::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -7.5px;
  left: 7.5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 7.5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7.5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 7.5px solid #ccc;
}

.cld-number.eventday {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.cld-number.eventday:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #eee;
}

.today .cld-number.eventday:hover {
  background: #888;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Hello</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="caleandar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Для разных `div` или для разных страниц?

Comment: @Denis640Kb Для разных div на разных страницах

Comment: тоже самое, что и в ответе, только на разных страницах.

Comment: @Denis640Kb Большое спасибо, все работает. А есть возможность сделать через админпанель редактирование дат событий events ?

Comment: да, конечно. Если Вы используете только javascript, то Вы можете создать файл, к примеру, `settings`, и через `localstorage` или сессию передать этот параметр в нужный Вам файл.

Comment: @Denis640Kb про localstorage  почитал, но не понимаю, как связать с админкой вордпресс. Наверно, надо новую тему открывать?(   Подскажите, если можно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем и целом - надо сделать следующее:
У Вас в функцию `caleandar` передаются 3 параметра.
1.Вам надо для каждого `div` задать свой `id` и одинаковый класс. 
2.Выносите `events` из функции (Вы и так можете их передать в `caleandar`)
3.Задаёте разные ивенты (Чтобы для каждого календаря свои даты отображались) В примере это `events1` и `events2`.
4.Ищете все элементы по классу, которые задали в пункте 1. 
5.Проверяете календарь по `id`, и для каждого из них присваиваете свой `events`.

Пример:

```js
 var Calendar = function(model, options, date) {
        // Default Values
        this.Options = {
            Color: '',
            LinkColor: '',
            NavShow: true,
            NavVertical: false,
            NavLocation: '',
            DateTimeShow: true,
            DateTimeFormat: 'mmm, yyyy',
            DatetimeLocation: '',
            EventClick: '',
            EventTargetWholeDay: false,
            DisabledDays: [],
            ModelChange: model
        };
        // Overwriting default values
        for (var key in options) {
            this.Options[key] = typeof options[key] == 'string' ? options[key].toLowerCase() : options[key];
        }

        model ? this.Model = model : this.Model = {};
        this.Today = new Date();

        this.Selected = this.Today
        this.Today.Month = this.Today.getMonth();
        this.Today.Year = this.Today.getFullYear();
        if (date) {
            this.Selected = date
        }
        this.Selected.Month = this.Selected.getMonth();
        this.Selected.Year = this.Selected.getFullYear();

        this.Selected.Days = new Date(this.Selected.Year, (this.Selected.Month + 1), 0).getDate();
        this.Selected.FirstDay = new Date(this.Selected.Year, (this.Selected.Month), 1).getDay();
        this.Selected.LastDay = new Date(this.Selected.Year, (this.Selected.Month + 1), 0).getDay();

        this.Prev = new Date(this.Selected.Year, (this.Selected.Month - 1), 1);
        if (this.Selected.Month == 0) {
            this.Prev = new Date(this.Selected.Year - 1, 11, 1);
        }
        this.Prev.Days = new Date(this.Prev.getFullYear(), (this.Prev.getMonth() + 1), 0).getDate();
    };

    function createCalendar(calendar, element, adjuster) {
        if (typeof adjuster !== 'undefined') {
            var newDate = new Date(calendar.Selected.Year, calendar.Selected.Month + adjuster, 1);
            calendar = new Calendar(calendar.Model, calendar.Options, newDate);
            element.innerHTML = '';
        } else {
            for (var key in calendar.Options) {
                typeof calendar.Options[key] != 'function' && typeof calendar.Options[key] != 'object' && calendar.Options[key] ? element.className += " " + key + "-" + calendar.Options[key] : 0;
            }
        }
        var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

        function AddSidebar() {
            var sidebar = document.createElement('div');
            sidebar.className += 'cld-sidebar';

            var monthList = document.createElement('ul');
            monthList.className += 'cld-monthList';

            for (var i = 0; i < months.length - 3; i++) {
                var x = document.createElement('li');
                x.className += 'cld-month';
                var n = i - (4 - calendar.Selected.Month);
                // Account for overflowing month values
                if (n < 0) {
                    n += 12;
                } else if (n > 11) {
                    n -= 12;
                }
                // Add Appropriate Class
                if (i == 0) {
                    x.className += ' cld-rwd cld-nav';
                    x.addEventListener('click', function() {
                        typeof calendar.Options.ModelChange == 'function' ? calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange() : calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange;
                        createCalendar(calendar, element, -1);
                    });
                    x.innerHTML += '<svg height="15" width="15" viewBox="0 0 100 75" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"><polyline points="0,75 100,75 50,0"></polyline></svg>';
                } else if (i == months.length - 4) {
                    x.className += ' cld-fwd cld-nav';
                    x.addEventListener('click', function() {
                        typeof calendar.Options.ModelChange == 'function' ? calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange() : calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange;
                        createCalendar(calendar, element, 1);
                    });
                    x.innerHTML += '<svg height="15" width="15" viewBox="0 0 100 75" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"><polyline points="0,0 100,0 50,75"></polyline></svg>';
                } else {
                    if (i < 4) {
                        x.className += ' cld-pre';
                    } else if (i > 4) {
                        x.className += ' cld-post';
                    } else {
                        x.className += ' cld-curr';
                    }

                    //prevent losing var adj value (for whatever reason that is happening)
                    (function() {
                        var adj = (i - 4);
                        //x.addEventListener('click', function(){createCalendar(calendar, element, adj);console.log('kk', adj);} );
                        x.addEventListener('click', function() {
                            typeof calendar.Options.ModelChange == 'function' ? calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange() : calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange;
                            createCalendar(calendar, element, adj);
                        });
                        x.setAttribute('style', 'opacity:' + (1 - Math.abs(adj) / 4));
                        x.innerHTML += months[n].substr(0, 3);
                    }()); // immediate invocation

                    if (n == 0) {
                        var y = document.createElement('li');
                        y.className += 'cld-year';
                        if (i < 5) {
                            y.innerHTML += calendar.Selected.Year;
                        } else {
                            y.innerHTML += calendar.Selected.Year + 1;
                        }
                        monthList.appendChild(y);
                    }
                }
                monthList.appendChild(x);
            }
            sidebar.appendChild(monthList);
            if (calendar.Options.NavLocation) {
                document.getElementById(calendar.Options.NavLocation).innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById(calendar.Options.NavLocation).appendChild(sidebar);
            } else {
                element.appendChild(sidebar);
            }
        }

        var mainSection = document.createElement('div');
        mainSection.className += "cld-main";

        function AddDateTime() {
            var datetime = document.createElement('div');
            datetime.className += "cld-datetime";
            if (calendar.Options.NavShow && !calendar.Options.NavVertical) {
                var rwd = document.createElement('div');
                rwd.className += " cld-rwd cld-nav";
                rwd.addEventListener('click', function() {
                    createCalendar(calendar, element, -1);
                });
                rwd.innerHTML = '<svg height="15" width="15" viewBox="0 0 75 100" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"><polyline points="0,50 75,0 75,100"></polyline></svg>';
                datetime.appendChild(rwd);
            }
            var today = document.createElement('div');
            today.className += ' today';
            today.innerHTML = months[calendar.Selected.Month] + ", " + calendar.Selected.Year;
            datetime.appendChild(today);
            if (calendar.Options.NavShow && !calendar.Options.NavVertical) {
                var fwd = document.createElement('div');
                fwd.className += " cld-fwd cld-nav";
                fwd.addEventListener('click', function() {
                    createCalendar(calendar, element, 1);
                });
                fwd.innerHTML = '<svg height="15" width="15" viewBox="0 0 75 100" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"><polyline points="0,0 75,50 0,100"></polyline></svg>';
                datetime.appendChild(fwd);
            }
            if (calendar.Options.DatetimeLocation) {
                document.getElementById(calendar.Options.DatetimeLocation).innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById(calendar.Options.DatetimeLocation).appendChild(datetime);
            } else {
                mainSection.appendChild(datetime);
            }
        }

        function AddLabels() {
            var labels = document.createElement('ul');
            labels.className = 'cld-labels';
            var labelsList = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
            for (var i = 0; i < labelsList.length; i++) {
                var label = document.createElement('li');
                label.className += "cld-label";
                label.innerHTML = labelsList[i];
                labels.appendChild(label);
            }
            mainSection.appendChild(labels);
        }

        function AddDays() {
            // Create Number Element
            function DayNumber(n) {
                var number = document.createElement('p');
                number.className += "cld-number";
                number.innerHTML += n;
                return number;
            }
            var days = document.createElement('ul');
            days.className += "cld-days";
            // Previous Month's Days
            for (var i = 0; i < (calendar.Selected.FirstDay); i++) {
                var day = document.createElement('li');
                day.className += "cld-day prevMonth";
                //Disabled Days
                var d = i % 7;
                for (var q = 0; q < calendar.Options.DisabledDays.length; q++) {
                    if (d == calendar.Options.DisabledDays[q]) {
                        day.className += " disableDay";
                    }
                }

                var number = DayNumber((calendar.Prev.Days - calendar.Selected.FirstDay) + (i + 1));
                day.appendChild(number);

                days.appendChild(day);
            }
            // Current Month's Days
            for (var i = 0; i < calendar.Selected.Days; i++) {
                var day = document.createElement('li');
                day.className += "cld-day currMonth";
                //Disabled Days
                var d = (i + calendar.Selected.FirstDay) % 7;
                for (var q = 0; q < calendar.Options.DisabledDays.length; q++) {
                    if (d == calendar.Options.DisabledDays[q]) {
                        day.className += " disableDay";
                    }
                }
                var number = DayNumber(i + 1);
                // Check Date against Event Dates
                for (var n = 0; n < calendar.Model.length; n++) {
                    var evDate = calendar.Model[n].Date;
                    var toDate = new Date(calendar.Selected.Year, calendar.Selected.Month, (i + 1));
                    if (evDate.getTime() == toDate.getTime()) {
                        number.className += " eventday";
                        var title = document.createElement('span');
                        title.className += "cld-title";
                        if (typeof calendar.Model[n].Link == 'function' || calendar.Options.EventClick) {
                            var a = document.createElement('a');
                            a.setAttribute('href', '#');
                            a.innerHTML += calendar.Model[n].Title;
                            if (calendar.Options.EventClick) {
                                var z = calendar.Model[n].Link;
                                if (typeof calendar.Model[n].Link != 'string') {
                                    a.addEventListener('click', calendar.Options.EventClick.bind.apply(calendar.Options.EventClick, [null].concat(z)));
                                    if (calendar.Options.EventTargetWholeDay) {
                                        day.className += " clickable";
                                        day.addEventListener('click', calendar.Options.EventClick.bind.apply(calendar.Options.EventClick, [null].concat(z)));
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    a.addEventListener('click', calendar.Options.EventClick.bind(null, z));
                                    if (calendar.Options.EventTargetWholeDay) {
                                        day.className += " clickable";
                                        day.addEventListener('click', calendar.Options.EventClick.bind(null, z));
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                a.addEventListener('click', calendar.Model[n].Link);
                                if (calendar.Options.EventTargetWholeDay) {
                                    day.className += " clickable";
                                    day.addEventListener('click', calendar.Model[n].Link);
                                }
                            }
                            title.appendChild(a);
                        } else {
                            title.innerHTML += '<a href="' + calendar.Model[n].Link + '">' + calendar.Model[n].Title + '</a>';
                        }
                        number.appendChild(title);
                    }
                }
                day.appendChild(number);
                // If Today..
                if ((i + 1) == calendar.Today.getDate() && calendar.Selected.Month == calendar.Today.Month && calendar.Selected.Year == calendar.Today.Year) {
                    day.className += " today";
                }
                days.appendChild(day);
            }
            // Next Month's Days
            // Always same amount of days in calander
            var extraDays = 13;
            if (days.children.length > 35) {
                extraDays = 6;
            } else if (days.children.length < 29) {
                extraDays = 20;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < (extraDays - calendar.Selected.LastDay); i++) {
                var day = document.createElement('li');
                day.className += "cld-day nextMonth";
                //Disabled Days
                var d = (i + calendar.Selected.LastDay + 1) % 7;
                for (var q = 0; q < calendar.Options.DisabledDays.length; q++) {
                    if (d == calendar.Options.DisabledDays[q]) {
                        day.className += " disableDay";
                    }
                }

                var number = DayNumber(i + 1);
                day.appendChild(number);

                days.appendChild(day);
            }
            mainSection.appendChild(days);
        }
        if (calendar.Options.Color) {
            mainSection.innerHTML += '<style>.cld-main{color:' + calendar.Options.Color + ';}</style>';
        }
        if (calendar.Options.LinkColor) {
            mainSection.innerHTML += '<style>.cld-title a{color:' + calendar.Options.LinkColor + ';}</style>';
        }
        element.appendChild(mainSection);

        if (calendar.Options.NavShow && calendar.Options.NavVertical) {
            AddSidebar();
        }
        if (calendar.Options.DateTimeShow) {
            AddDateTime();
        }
        AddLabels();
        AddDays();
    }

    function caleandar(el, data, settings) {
        var obj = new Calendar(data, settings);
        createCalendar(obj, el);
    }

    var settings = {
        Color: 'blue',
        LinkColor: 'red',
        EventClick: ''
    };

    var events2 = [{
        'Date': new Date(2020, 0, 07),
        'Title': 'Doctor appointment at 3:25pm.'
    },
        {
            'Date': new Date(2020, 0, 28),
            'Link': 'https://garfield.com'
        },
        {
            'Date': new Date(2020, 0, 27),
            'Link': 'http://google.com/'
        },
    ];

    var events1 = [{
        'Date': new Date(2020, 0, 01),
        'Title': 'Doctor appointment at 3:25pm.'
    },
        {
            'Date': new Date(2020, 0, 21),
            'Link': 'https://garfield.com'
        },
        {
            'Date': new Date(2020, 0, 17),
            'Link': 'http://google.com/'
        },
    ];

    let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('calendar');
    for (let elem of elements) {
        var zz = elem.getAttribute('id');
        if (zz == 'caleandar1'){
            var eventsz = events1;
        } else {
            var eventsz = events2;
        }
        caleandar(elem, eventsz, settings);
    }
```

```css
 .cld-main {
        width: 330px;
    }

    .cld-main a {
        color: #333;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .cld-datetime {
        position: relative;
        width: 66%;
        min-width: 100px;
        max-width: 300px;
        margin: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .cld-datetime .today {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        width: calc(100% - 40px);
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .cld-nav {
        position: relative;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        margin-top: 2px;
    }

    .cld-nav:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .cld-nav:hover svg {
        fill: #666;
    }

    .cld-rwd {
        float: left;
    }

    .cld-fwd {
        float: right;
    }

    .cld-nav svg:hover {}

    .cld-labels,
    .cld-days {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    .cld-label,
    .cld-day {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 14.28%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .cld-day.today .cld-number {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        background: #666;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .cld-day.disableDay {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .cld-day.nextMonth,
    .cld-day.prevMonth {
        opacity: 0.33;
    }

    .cld-number {
        position: relative;
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .cld-title {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 5;
        display: none;
        top: 30px;
        left: 0;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        background: #fff;
        white-space: nowrap;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .cld-number:hover .cld-title {
        display: block;
    }

    .cld-title::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: -7.5px;
        left: 7.5px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 7.5px solid transparent;
        border-right: 7.5px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 7.5px solid #ccc;
    }

    .cld-number.eventday {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
    }

    .cld-number.eventday:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        background: #eee;
    }

    .today .cld-number.eventday:hover {
        background: #888;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="caleandar" class="calendar"></div>
<div id="caleandar1" class="calendar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Буду разбираться!